# how to deal Chinese garbled in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

when I send an object(contain chinese) in the client,I just recevie the Chinese garbled.how to do it?

client:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:3001');
let obj = {name:'小明',department:'学校',accountID:'1111'};
socket.emit('department_online',JSON.stringify(obj));
socket.on('success',(data)=>{
  console.log(data);
}
```

sever:

```
//部门连接
    socket.on('department_online', function (data) {
        socket.name = data.name;
        if (!departmentArr[data.name]) {
            departmentArr[data.name] = data;
        }
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('success',data);
       //可以进行相关操作
    });
```

then:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvO11.png)

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe it broken.npm install socket.io-clinet again,then work